# JavaScript: What's the difference between window.top and top.window

Tags: javascript, window

I have been recently been reading into the JavaScript `top` functionality and noticed that I can run either `window.top` or `top.window`. From what I can see there is no difference in functionality so it seems to be strange that it is possible to run both.

```js
// They appear to be the same here at least:
console.log(window.top === top.window);
```

[MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/top)

My question is, does anyone know why this functionality exists twice and are there any differences between the two? I am wondering about things like differences in browser support, or quirky bugs related to running it one way or another.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`window` is the global object, so properties on it can be accessed as if they were standalone variables. So referencing `top` on the top level is the same as referencing `window.top`. So the question boils down to the difference is between

```
window.top
```

and

```
window.top.window
```

`window.top` gives you a window object (it may be the same as `window`, or it may be an outer window, if you're in an iframe), and a window's `window` property is a reference to the same `window` object (it's a weird self-reference), so those two references are exactly the same as well. You can count on

```
window.top === window.top.window
```

to always be `true`.

Comment: Very informative, thanks! So the second part of my question would be, why? Why can window reference itself? As it is also possible to do `window.window` and `window.window.window.window` and so on.

Comment: [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/window): The point of having the `window` property refer to the object itself, was likely to make it easy to refer to the global object. Otherwise, you'd have to do a manual `var window = this;` assignment at the top of your script. Yes, you can chain `window`s infinitely, just like `obj = {}; obj.obj = obj; obj.obj.obj.obj.obj === obj` will give `true`